# How to swap two slices in a byte array?

Tags: go

I try to swap the slice 0:10 and the slice 10:20 using the following code. But

```
  data1 := make([]byte, 100)
  tmp := data1[0:10]
  data1[0:10] = data1[10:20]
  data1[10:20] = tmp
```

But I got error messages like this.

```
../xxx.go:60:14: cannot assign to data1[0:10]
../xxx.go:61:15: cannot assign to data1[10:20]
```

Could anybody show me how to swap two slices in a byte array? Thanks.

Comment: If you were to do this in C, you'd use a `memcpy`. You can effectively do the same thing in Go if you use Cgo to call `memcpy` and the `unsafe` library to get a direct pointer to your underlying array.

Comment: How can you swap memory without using other storage using memcpy? If you want to use extra storage you can do the same in go using copy().

Comment: @jcdi see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987073/1218512).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to swap the contents of the underlying array. The only way of doing it is to swap individual elements:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    data[i], data[i+10] = data[i+10], data[i]
}
```

Or:

```
j := 10
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]
    j++
}
```

Comment: Instead of a separate variable `j` you could have just used `i+10`

Answer (score 2):

@BurakSerdar 's answer is the most efficient for the small chunks of data to move and the swap nature of the operation.

If you're curious how to copy sections of a slice, simply use the internal `copy` function:

```
copy(data[0:10], data[10:20]) // overwrites first 10-bytes with next 10 bytes
```

To perform a swap with copy is a little awkward, but if you're curious:

```
// tmp := data[0:10] // will *NOT* work
//                   // as `tmp` will just reference data's underlying byte-array

tmp := make([]byte, 10) // need fresh memory
copy(tmp, data[0:10])

copy(data[0:10], data[10:20])

copy(data[10:20], tmp)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ud31Gxfa19b

Comment: So the `copy` solution will be faster than the for-loop solution?

Comment: It really depends on the situation. For a large block of memory I would expect `copy` to be more optimized. But for your "swap" operation, one does need temp buffer - so there's that penalty. Maybe you could set aside a permanent buffer for that temp space - so it did not need to be allocated each time. One would have to [benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) all of this to know for sure, as each target architecture instruction set is different, plus compiler optimizations add a lot of unknowns. Measuring for your specific use case is the only way to know which is better.